# Magento2: Block with shipping methods dissapper after 1 sec

Tags: magento2

When i try configure shipping methods after select this tab. Blocks They appear on the second and disappear. How to solve it?

[image]

M 2.3.4

log:

```
[2020-04-10 18:55:43] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
[2020-04-10 18:55:43] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
[2020-04-10 18:55:47] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
[2020-04-10 18:55:47] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js' [] []
```

I try deploy, delete pub/static etc but still no work. Any other solution?

Comment: Have you installed any third party extension of shipping method?

Comment: We do not have third part extension of shipping method. But the same issue is in tab "TAX"

Comment: You can please enable the error log from "app/bootstrap.php" file and check if you find any specific error. That might give you some hint to resolve it further.

Comment: can you please let me know how can I enable log from this file?

Comment: There is one line "ini_set('display_errors', 1);" written in this file. You need to just remove "#" written ahead of this line. Once you remove comment, you will be able to see any php error you are getting.